# 'string index out of range' when replacing first and last characaters of string?

Tags: python, string, indexing

I am trying to exchange the first and last characters of a string but 'string index out of range' error is occurring. Please help

```
def front_back(str):
        ind=len(str)-1
        newstring=str.replace(str[0],str[ind])
        newerstring=newstring.replace(newstring[ind],str[0])
        return newerstring
```

Comment: running your code doesnt reutnr any index out of range error. also replace will erplace all instances of the char, not just the first, lastly you are overwriting the python built in type of string, try to give your variables names that are not the asme as python builtin names

Comment: Did you check if the string is empty?

Comment: I had used python 2.7 -- for clarification -- and no, the string was not empty Anand. It was inside a function so it was required to be put in as an argument by the user.

Comment: @AritraChakrabary you clearly have not read the documentation for `str.replace` lets say you have the word `testing`, your code `str.replace(str[0],str[ind])` will first have the parameters interpolated so it becomes `str.replace('t', 'g')`. the documentation for replace says `Return a copy with ALL occurrences of substring old replaced by new.` so everywhere you had a `t` would be replaced with a `g`. So `testing` becomes `gesging` as ALL `t` is replaced with `g`.

Comment: @chris you're right . But can you help me with the problem ? The program is indeed replacing all instances of the char. Help. Just ran the program.

Comment: @AritraChakrabary someone already posted an answer that solves this.

Comment: please add a link to that

Comment: I am going offline

Answer (score 2):

String objects are immutable, means it accepts no change in its elements.
The [.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method is just returning a new instance of string.

You can try this way:

```
def front_back(s):
    return s[-1] + s[1:-1] + s[0] if len(s) >= 2 else s

print(front_back('hi there'))  #output:  ei therh
```

Comment: Thanks and good program! But the problem is -- why can't I do this with the replace method on string object

Comment: but there's a catch. this program is not working in python 2.7---'string index out of range'!!!!!!! Making me go mad. Though this is working in python 3

Comment: @AritraChakrabary It is working in python2x too( just print isn't called as function). You can't use replace to modify same object since it is non -mutable. This feature has its own pros.